# left shift and angular brackets don't work

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have bought a new laptop and installed ubuntu, but some keys on the keyboard are not working, especially left shift, angular brackets and FN.
Could someone help me with that ?

OS is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Computer is ASUS ROG STRIX SCAR15 G533QR
I've got an azerty keyboard (I'm French) without numeric keypad
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ5qK.jpg)

Here are a few command outputs:

gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
*@as []*

cat /etc/default/keyboard
*XKBLAYOUT=fr

XKBVARIANT=azerty

BACKSPACE=guess*

localectl status
*System Locale: LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8

VC Keymap: fr

X11 Layout: fr

X11 Variant: azerty*

setxkbmap -print
*xkb_keymap {

xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(azerty)" };

xkb_types     { include "complete"  };

xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };

xkb_symbols   { include "pc+fr(azerty)+fr(oss):2+inet(evdev)"  };

xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };

};*

setxkbmap -query
*rules:      evdev

model:      pc105

layout:     fr,fr

variant:    azerty,oss*

When I use xev and hit the Shift-left key the angular-bracket key or the fn key, nothing happens.

Maybe it's the geometry setting that is incorrect but I don't know what is the one for my laptop nor how to change it

Thank you so much for your help
Emmanuel

Comment: are you aware that you have set two Fr layouts - azerty and oss?

Comment: @Andra : No I was not aware of that :) How I can fix this ?

Comment: run `setxkbmap -layout "fr" -variant "azerty"` in terminal

Comment: @Andra : thanks Andra. I've run the command, I now get : setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     fr
variant:    azerty
but it didn't fix my initial issue : left shift key and angular brackets key still don't work...

Comment: maybe they are broken? you may try, for example, connect a usb keyboard or launch a liveusb system to see if it works another way. Or I just tried on my computer: do these keys work in onscreen keyboard (Onboard)?